# EditText different state after user inserting content

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two `EditText` with two states. A focused state and a default state.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/not_focused" />
</selector>
```

This is working as expected and the states differ only in the background (color, etc).

I've added `setOnFocusChangeListener` on the edittext to detect the focus.

How can I set the state of my edittext to be the same as the focused state only if I have any content in my edittext? (for example after user inserting some input)?

In the `setOnFocusChangeListener` I can detect the edittext is focused and if it has any content but I can't figure it out how to maintain the focused state, that is, the same background

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TextWatcher` to check when the text changes, then inside that, add an `IF`, then inside that `IF` check if the `EditText` is different from `null`, and, add your code.

What this will do, is that anytime the text inside the `EditText` changes, it will call the `IF` and see wether or not it has text inside and accordingly change it.

Comment: Yes. I'm already doing that but the problem is setting the state as the same as when it is focused

Comment: @Favolas Doesn't the same code that you used on the `setOnFocusChangeListner` work?

Comment: No. I'm using a background selector.